# Not getting comment notifications for my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments

I run a Facebook page and when someone posts a comment, I should get a notification.

This used to work fine. I would get notifications everytime someone would comment my stuff. Suddenly, it stopped working and I can't fix it.

I noticed this about 2 months ago. Could it be that it stopped sending notifications because I am writing less that I wrote for about 3 months?

I suppose this is a recurrent problem, since I have found other people asking [this question](https://feedback.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10106039419871079).

Here are the notifications settings of my page

[image: fb page notifications settings]

Comment: Why the downvote?